# Dual-boot Ubuntu and Win 10 resulting in 2 empty partitions

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

I decided to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (dual-boot). I've unchecked things like Fast Startup and Secure Boot and I freed 30 GB space in diskmgmt.msc for Linux. Then I installed Ubuntu with my USB.

Everything was right, installation showed up as successfull, but while restarting the computer there didn't appear any grub menu where I could choose the OS.

I tried some solutions found in the internet like the command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

but it didn't help.

Then I looked up again in the diskmgmt.msc and I found 2 completely empty partitions with total size of these 30 GB I released before. I don't know why, but it seems that Ubuntu installation only created these 2 partitions and that's it.

Just to make it clear, while installing Ubuntu I've chosen for "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option (or something like this), not the "Something else" option.

The question is, did I actually really successfully install Ubuntu, and if yes, how to make the grub menu appear, and if not, what should I do then? Delete these partitions to make free space for Ubuntu or just reinstall Ubuntu using the USB?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What brand/model system? There is both UEFI fast boot and Windows fast start up. You need both off. System should install to 30GB, I currently use 11GB, but have all data normally in /home in another partition, so you do not have a lot of room for large data files. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8 https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu installation has probably failed, as 30 GB is too near to the bare minimum.
The
 [Installation System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)
recommended minimum is 25 GB, but does not say with which installation options.

If you wish to try again, I suggest to unify the two partitions into
one partition of 60 GB for the installation.

However, you should know that Ubuntu is now available inside Windows via the
Microsoft Store. This is much safer than dual boot and requires no partition
work.

Comment: Moved, posted in wrong place.